# how to add data in a svg element appended in a div

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am looking it to following code which i have borrowed from a jsfiddle.

```
var svg = d3.select("#calendars").selectAll("svg")
 .data(firstDayOfEachMonth)
.enter().append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
.append("g")
attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - cellSize * 7 - 1) + "," + ((height   
 -    cellSize * 6) / 2) + ")");
```

I wish to use this code under a div. for this i created a div and appended an svg element in to it but than i am failed to understand how to used the above code with my svg element :

```
 mydiv = d3.select("body")  
.append("div")
.attr("id","MainDiv")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("font-size", "18px") 
.style("background", "gray")
.style("border", "1px black solid")
.style("border-radius", 4+"px")
.style("top", (15)+"px")
.style("left",(15)+"px")
.style("height",245+"px")
.style("width",245+"px")
.style("visibility", "visible");
 mysvg= mydiv.append("svg")
```

i than used following code but it did not work any suggestion please.

```
 var svg = d3.select("#calendars").selectAll("svg")
 .data(firstDayOfEachMonth)
 .enter().append("mysvg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - cellSize * 7 - 1) + "," + ((height   
 -    cellSize * 6) / 2) + ")");
```

Comment: what do you want to add in it? bars, line chart ?

Comment: can you add some data and code here https://jsbin.com/sejejexeqa/edit?html,output

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thardy/uEjU8/
see the code above, i want to display this code under my created div.

Comment: you cannot append ("mysvg"). You have to append a string which is a SVG element, e.g. "svg", "rect",...

Comment: I also tried to this but it did not work. like i added the full object array of svg in to my div as mydiv.append(svg) where svg is :
     var svg = d3.select("#calendars").selectAll("svg")
     .data(firstDayOfEachMonth)
 .enter().append("mysvg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - cellSize * 7 - 1) + "," + ((height   
 -    cellSize * 6) / 2) + ")");

Comment: Again, you have to put a string in the append function not a selection.Why can't you use the JSFiddle as is - only change the d3.select("#calendars")... to d3.select("div.yourDiv")... where .yourDiv is any selector refering to your div - in this case a <div> with the class "yourDiv"